# Does Ahead Of Time compilation need warmup in jmh?

Tags: java, jmh

I was reading some documents about the java microbenchmark harness, I came accross this affirmation:

> Every online optimization requires warmup,Basics: Warmup JIT compilation is NOT the only online optimization.

Does this warmup phase still useful for a vm with ahead of time compilation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "some document", I assume, you mean some of my benchmarking talks. If you seen the video, there was the example of an "online optimization" that is not a JIT compilation: GC heuristics that adapt to the allocation rate dynamically.

The point of the assertion above was that all processes have the transient responses. When runtime (or even fully statically compiled application) shifts from zero to full execution, it needs time to adapt to new conditions: load, link, compile code, hydrate the application caches, start and balance threads for cores, wake up CPUs and settle on a sensible frequency, etc. etc. etc. All these are included in warmup. The next stage after that is steady state, when the system had fully adapted and transient responses settled. This is where you start benchmarking.

In other words, "JIT compilation is NOT the only online optimization".